# Rails: redirect_to more than 1 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to make a redirect_to more than one site? Currently I'm doing `redirect_to @sale.url` but can I also `redirect_to :back` in a new window at the same time?

Every solution is much appreciated (even the dirty ones ;) )

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to redirect_to to different addresses on the same condition?

Comment: As far as I know Rails do not permit having sereval redirection.

Comment: Can you give context?

Comment: After a create action I want to redirect_to the parent index view and at the same time (in a new window) to an external URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to only 1 URL at a time, but you can add some javascript to index file to open the 2nd window you want, and here we pass the URL also from the same controller, you can change URLs to whatever you want, even local URLs:

```
# sales_controller.rb
def create
  .....
  @new_window_url = "http://google.com"
  redirect_to sales_path
end

# sales/index.html.erb
<javascript> 
  window.open("#{@new_window_url}");
</javascript>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails (which is on the server) can't redirect the browser to more than one location: it makes a response and that response can only be one thing, not two different things at once.

However, javascript on the page can open a location in a new tab, and rails can write javascript which will be run on page load, or before submitting a form, for example.  So, you could, on submitting a form or clicking a link, open a location in a new tab, and then let rails redirect the current tab.  This would be a weird thing to do and is the sort of thing normally associated with horrible ad popups, like when you use a bit torrent site and it opens gambling/chinese wife tabs whenever you do something.

So, you probably don't really want to do it.  If you explain the context around what you're trying to do then someone can probably suggest a nicer way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect_to to different addresses on the same action on a same condition.

You can redirect basing on different conditions.If based on codition,
else you will get multiple redirection error.

```
address = redirect_address1
if some_condition
 address = redirect_address2
end
redirect_to address
```